# HTML / CSS - Creating forum - Any way of dynamically indenting tr's?

Tags: html, css, dynamic, html-table, margin

I am trying to create a forum (PHP will not be shown). Each post / reply is represented by two td's (first td has an image - the users profile picture -, the second td has text - what the user wrote - and has a width of 100%). The first post has no indent. The post can receive any amount of replies. Each reply can receive any amount of replies. I can't think of a way to dynamically indent the reply. Basically, I need a way to make a reply to a post have one 'indent', a reply to a reply should have two 'indents', a reply to a reply to a reply should have three 'indents' etc.

This is what I tried.
CSS:

```
tr {
    border-left: 20px solid transparent; /* this would be the indent which each reply will receive */
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr> <!-- this is the first reply to a post, so it should receive one indent -->
        <td class='first'><img src='proileImage.png' width='30px' /></td>
        <td class='second'>first reply</td>
    </tr>

    <tr> <!-- this is another reply to the post, so this should also get one indent -->
        <td class='first'><img src='proileImage.png' width='30px' /></td>
        <td class='second'>Second reply</td>

        <tr> <!--this is a reply to the second reply, so it should have two indents-->
            <td class='first'><img src='proileImage.png' width='30px' /></td>
            <td class='second'>Reply to second reply</td>
        </tr>

    </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, I was hoping that since the reply to the second reply is a tr inside of a tr, it would receive two border-left's of 20px (two indents) but it only was indented once by 20px. I also realized that placing tr's right inside of tr's is not valid.

Another solution I thought of (but was not a correct solution) was to put each reply inside an li (since li's receive a left margin, and li's inside li's will be indented as well) but then I found out that placing td's and tr's inside of ul's and li's is invalid.

I cannot think of a way to dynamically make each post / reply have one indent, and each reply to a reply have two indents etc. I cannot change what each post / reply consist of (has to consist of the two td's) but I can change anything else (the CSS, and html around the posts / replies). Can anyone think if a way where I can dynamically indent each post / reply, depending on if it is a reply, a reply to a reply etc.?

Does this belong on codegolf (https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: Nesting a `<tr>` within a `<tr>` is not valid HTML.  The only valid direct descendant of a `<tr>` is a `<td>` or `<th>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant just have another row inside of a td first off.  Use firebug or something to see that it just makes another row along with the first two.  Youll need another td and then a full table in that again.  This is going to be a pain in the neck for you though since the table cells will line up.  Maybe its just me but I would recommend using another node type like div or span or something (maybe even a list) and then write out a loop for the css either as child elements with a reply count loop or inline css on the individual elements.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably going to have to use divs within divs instead of table rows and data. TRs are difficult to format in terms of positioning. Unless you want to be old school and put tables within tables within tables? Divs would be a bit more fiddly but you'll get the result you want. One solution would probably to use jQuery something like:

```
$(".replyDiv").foreach(function(){
    // change css to margin-left:20px
});
```

**Edit:**

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/E2nfS/2/
Notice how each reply's Css just has margin-left:20px;
You could get the jquery to apply that to each subsequent div you have in a reply.
Hope it helps you visually understand what to do.